# Quiero repartir a 2 jugadores 2 cartas

Tags: python

Es un programa de cartas que reparte 2 cartas aleatoriamente. Lo que quiero hacer es que se las reparta a 2 jugadores diferentes pero no sé cómo hacer.

```
palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]

Mazo = []

for palo in palos:

    for rango in rangos:

       Mazo.append(rango + palo)
Mazo=set(list(Mazo))

import random

while len(Mazo)>2:
  Mazo.remove(random.choice(list(Mazo)))
  #print(Mazo)    

#print(Mazo)
print("\n")

for Carta in Mazo:
    print (Carta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma simple podría ser la siguiente:

```
import random

palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]

# Generamos el mazo de las 52 cartas
mazo = list(zip(palos * len(rangos), rangos* len(palos)))

jugador1 = []
jugador2 = []
# Desordenamos el mazo
random.shuffle(mazo)
while mazo:
  jugador1.append(mazo.pop())
  jugador2.append(mazo.pop())

print("Cartas jugador 2: {0}".format(jugador1))
print("Cartas jugador 2: {0}".format(jugador2))
```

En este ejemplo hacemos lo siguiente:

- Con `list(zip(palos * len(rangos), rangos* len(palos)))` generamos una lista de todo el mazo combinando palos y rangos mediante `zip()`.
- Con `random.shuffle(mazo)` desordenamos al azar el mazo
- Luego simplemente recorremos la lista mientras tenga carta y con el método `pop()` obtenemos una y la eliminamos de la lista al mismo tiempo
- Mantenemos dos listas para cada jugador y las vamos agregando a medida que pedimos cada carta con `pop()`
- Este ejemplo reparte completamente las cartas a los dos jugadores.

Si queremos solo repartir de a dos cartas, debemos hacer algo como esto:

```
import random

palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]

# Generamos el mazo de las 52 cartas
mazo = list(zip(palos * len(rangos), rangos* len(palos)))

jugador1 = []
jugador2 = []
# Desordenamos el mazo
random.shuffle(mazo)

jugador1.extend([mazo.pop(), mazo.pop()])
jugador2.extend([mazo.pop(), mazo.pop()])

print("Cartas jugador 2: {0}".format(jugador1))
print("Cartas jugador 2: {0}".format(jugador2))
```

Lo que hacemos es "extender" la lista de cartas de cada jugador con una nueva lista de dos elementos quitando dos cartas del mazo para cada jugador. La idea original tuya de mantener una lista de cartas del mazo completo es necesaria ya que es la única forma de asegurarnos que cada carta que pidamos no sea una que ya hubiéramos recibido.

Comment: hola patricio! me gusta la prolijidad de tu codigo.Sin embargo al ejecutarlo me tira de forma aleatoria varias cartas de esta manera:

Comment: Cartas jugador 2: [('s', '6'), ('h', 'J'), ('h', '8'), ('h', '4'), ('c', '5'), ('d', '9'), ('s', '7'), ('h', '6'), ('s', '8'), ('s', '5'), ('c', '3'), ('s', '9'), ('d', '2'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '8'), ('h', 'A'), ('d', '6'), ('c', '8'), ('s', '4'), ('c', 'A'), ('s', 'K'), ('h', '9'), ('s', '2'), ('d', 'J'), ('h', '5'), ('h', '3')]

Comment: Cartas jugador 2: [('d', 'Q'), ('d', '3'), ('d', '5'), ('d', '10'), ('h', '2'), ('d', 'K'), ('c', '10'), ('c', 'Q'), ('h', 'K'), ('c', 'J'), ('h', '10'), ('c', '7'), ('h', 'Q'), ('d', '4'), ('h', '7'), ('c', '4'), ('d', '7'), ('s', 'Q'), ('s', '3'), ('s', '10'), ('c', '9'), ('d', 'A'), ('s', 'J'), ('s', 'A'), ('c', '6'), ('c', 'K')]

Comment: Yo necesitaria que solo le de dos cartas a jugador 1 y 2 cartas a jugador 2.Asi me reparte muchisimas!!

Comment: El código lo que hace es repartir completamente el mazo, si solo quieres dos cartas simplemente debes hacer 2 `pop` por jugador. Ahora edito mi respuesta

Comment: Sos un genio,quedo perfecto! esto era lo q buscaba  gracias por tu ayuda si no te ofende,guardare tu perfil.Estoy en un proyecto de muy largo plazo y tengo interes en cuando lo termine de pagarles a los que colaboraron con mi proyecto ya sea de forma pequeña o grande y vos con tu respuesta has colaborado.Si no te molesta guardare tu perfil en una rchivo para recompensarte cuando este todo terminado

Answer (score 0):

Esta esta es una forma, donde defines la cantidad de cartas por jugador:

```
import random
palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]
cartas_por_jugador = 2

def draw_cartas():
    carta = random.choice(palos) + ' ' +str(random.choice(rangos))
    return [carta]


def stay_cartas(): 
    i = 0
    jugador = 1
    while i < len(rangos) and i < cartas_por_jugador*2:
        print("carta jugador", jugador, ":" , draw_cartas())
        i = i + 1 
        if(i == cartas_por_jugador):
            jugador = jugador + 1        
stay_cartas()
```

En este caso repartira 2 cartas por cada jugador, ejemplo de salida:

```
'carta jugador', 1, ':', ['d 3']
'carta jugador', 1, ':', ['c K']
'carta jugador', 2, ':', ['s J']
'carta jugador', 2, ':', ['h 3']
```

Comment: Hola Jorge! gracias por tu ayuda si no te ofende,guardare tu perfil.Estoy en un proyecto de muy largo plazo y tengo interes en cuando lo termine de pagarles a los que colaboraron con mi proyecto ya sea de forma pequeña o grande y vos con tu respuesta has colaborado.Si no te molesta guardare tu perfil en una rchivo para recompensarte cuando este todo terminado.Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y atencion!